# How can I use sqlite3 in my Ubuntu Phone app? (C++ backend)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, c++, sqlite

I want to create an app, which has a C++ backend and uses sqlite3.
I can connect to an Database in memory using the following code:`m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE"); m_db.setDatabaseName(":memory:"); m_db.open();`

But I don't know what path I have to use or whatelse I have to do to create a local database file on my phone. If I run the application on my Computer I can replace `":memory:"` by any path I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the clue from a comment to this question that I can't find anymore.

If you want to write to/read from the filesystem you have to take care of the app confinement of Ubuntu. An normal not OS trusted application can only write to some limited "private" directories and read from some more directories. You can use the [QStandardPaths](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) class to find these directories.
For example to get the writable data directory I use `QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DataLocation)` and with `QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::DataLocation)` you get all readable data directories. It works for me to create my sqlite3 file in the writeable data directory.

By the way: You can get other kinds of directories for your application using [QStandardPaths](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) (eg. temp, cache, ...).

The app confinements of Ubuntu are available [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/platform/guides/app-confinement/).